# If-else with two possible ways

Tags: java, android, if-statement

Could you please help me find a solution for my code? I'm making a new Android app in which I need to make some calculations and the scenario is the following:

There are four fields to be calculated. Two EditText (number decimal) field are obligatory and the other two are optional, BUT, if the optional fields are filled, then it needs to be in the calculation, otherwise only the obligatory fields will be used.

Right now I'm totally OK with calculating the obligatory fields but when I try some if-else clause to include the optional fields in the calculation, the app goes bananas.
I'm not sure where I should make this two-step option, if I should use boolean to check the option field condition, if I just keep using if-else...
The problem is not the calculatin itself, but having two ways for the code to follow: One using only the obligatory fields if nothing else is inserted and the other one using all four fields.

Thanks everyone!

Code below is only using the two obligatory fields.

```
public void calcularResultado(View view) {

    //check for blank values in obligatory fields
    if (editGasolina.length() == 0) {
        editGasolina.setError("Insira o valor");
    }
    if (editEtanol.length() == 0) {
        editEtanol.setError("Insira o valor");

    //runs the code
    } else {

        double valorGasolina = Double.parseDouble(editGasolina.getText().toString());
        double valorEtanol = Double.parseDouble(editEtanol.getText().toString());

        double valorResultado = valorEtanol / valorGasolina;
        double porcentagem = (valorResultado) * 100;
        String valorResultadoTexto = Double.toString(porcentagem);
        valorResultadoTexto = String.format("%.2f", porcentagem);

        if (valorResultado >= 0.7) {
            textResultado.setText("GASOLINA");
            textRendimento.setText(valorResultadoTexto + "%");
        } else {
            textResultado.setText("ETANOL");
            textRendimento.setText(valorResultadoTexto + "%");
        }
```

Comment: What would this calculation output?

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. What happens now, since you have an `if-if-else`construction, it considers the first `if` statement to be seperate from the `if-else` block below. That is to say, if `editEtanol.length() == 0` evaluates to false, it will execute the `else` block below, even if `editGasolina.length() == 0` evaluates to `true`.

Changing the line `if (editEtanol.length() == 0) {` to `else if (editEtanol.length() == 0) {` should already help alot. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void calcularResultado(View view) {

//check for blank values in obligatory fields
if (editGasolina.length() == 0) {
    editGasolina.setError("Insira o valor");
}
if (editEtanol.length() == 0) {
    editEtanol.setError("Insira o valor");

//runs the code
} else {

    double valorGasolina = Double.parseDouble(editGasolina.getText().toString());
    double valorEtanol = Double.parseDouble(editEtanol.getText().toString());

    boolean optionalField1Used = optionalEditText1.length() != 0;
    boolean optionalField2Used = optionalEditText2.length() != 0;

    double valorResultado = 0;

    if (!optionalField1Used && !optionalField2Used) {
         valorResultado = valorEtanol / valorGasolina;
    } else if (optionalField1Used && !optionalField2Used) {
         valorResultado = //some other calculation
    } else if (!optionalField1Used && optionalField2Used) {
         valorResultado = //yet another calculation
    } else {
          valorResultado = //calculation if both optional fields used
    }

    double porcentagem = (valorResultado) * 100;
    String valorResultadoTexto = Double.toString(porcentagem);
    valorResultadoTexto = String.format("%.2f", porcentagem);

    if (valorResultado >= 0.7) {
        textResultado.setText("GASOLINA");
        textRendimento.setText(valorResultadoTexto + "%");
    } else {
        textResultado.setText("ETANOL");
        textRendimento.setText(valorResultadoTexto + "%");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that the optional fields are called `edit1` and `edit2`. I also assume that in order to use the alternative computation, both optional values must be present.

To enhance code clarity, I would define two Boolean variables to explicitly indicate whether the mandatory and optional fields have values. Something like the following.

```
public void calcularResultado(View view) {
    var mandatoryValues = true;
    var optionalValues = false;
    if (editGasolina.length() == 0 { 
        editGasolina.setError("Insira o valor");
        mandatoryValues = false;
    } 
    if (editEtanol.length() == 0 { 
        editEtanol.setError("Insira o valor"); 
        mandatoryValues = false;
    }
    if (edit1.length() > 0 && edit2.length() > 0) {
        optionalValues = true;
    }
    if (mandatoryValues) {
        if (optionalValues) {
            // do alternative computation 
        } else {
            // do computation for mandatory values only
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if either mandatory value is absent, no computation is performed.

Hope it helps - Carlos